# Precondition check failed when using Gmail API and service account

Tags: java, spring, gmail-api

I made a service file to send emails to users, however I encountered an issue with the credentials file. I have set the domain delegation in the Admin console, and I have gave all the required IAM roles to the user who is impersonating the service account. I was able to send an emails before using a service account key but I changed it to create an application default env var using the GCLI.

I am using these libraries for gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.auth:google-auth-library-credentials:1.23.0'
implementation 'com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:1.23.0'
implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-gmail:v1-rev20221219-2.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.sun.mail:javax.mail:1.6.0'
implementation 'javax.mail:javax.mail-api:1.6.2'
```

Here is the error I got after sending the request to send an email to the user.

```
POST https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/myuser@mydomain.com/messages/send
{
  "code": 400,
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "global",
      "message": "Precondition check failed.",
      "reason": "failedPrecondition"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Precondition check failed.",
  "status": "FAILED_PRECONDITION"
}
```

Here is my service file that I created to send the email. most of the send email functionality comes from google Gmail API docs for Java.

```
@Service
public class GoogleService {

    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "myapp";

    @Value("${server.port}")
    @Nullable
    private Integer port;

    private Gmail service;

    public GoogleService() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        final GoogleCredentials credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.getApplicationDefault().createScoped(GmailScopes.GMAIL_SEND).createDelegated("no-reply@mydomain.com");
        final HttpRequestInitializer requestInitializer = new HttpCredentialsAdapter(credentials);

        this.service = new Gmail.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), requestInitializer).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
    }

    public void sendEmail(String bodyText, String messageSubject, String toEmailAddress) throws IOException, MessagingException, GeneralSecurityException{
        Properties props = new Properties();
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        MimeMessage email = new MimeMessage(session);
        email.setFrom(new InternetAddress("no-reply@mydomain.com"));
        email.addRecipient(RecipientType.TO,
            new InternetAddress(toEmailAddress));
        email.setSubject(messageSubject);
        email.setText(bodyText);

        // Encode and wrap the MIME message into a gmail message
        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        email.writeTo(buffer);
        byte[] rawMessageBytes = buffer.toByteArray();
        String encodedEmail = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(rawMessageBytes);
        Message message = new Message();
        message.setRaw(encodedEmail);

        try {
        // Create send message
        Message sentMessage = service.users().messages().send("me", message).execute();
            System.out.println("Message id: " + sentMessage .getId());
            System.out.println(sentMessage .toPrettyString());
        } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
            // TODO(developer) - handle error appropriately
            GoogleJsonError error = e.getDetails();
            if (error.getCode() == 403) {
                System.err.println("Unable to send message: " + e.getDetails());
            } else {
                throw e;
            }
        }    
      }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
.setServiceAccountUser(userEmail)
```

instead of createDelegated

Comment: Thank you for your response, however this is the most updated google library which does not have that method.